# sub-parameter in symfony configuration

Tags: php, symfony

I try to call a sub parameter in my symfony configuration. example :

```
parameters:
    param.languages:
        en:
            - en
            - fr
        fr:
            - fr
            - en
```

And I want to include the "en" subparameter of "param.languages" in my config like :

```
services:
    app.mailer:
        class:     AppBundle\Mailer
        arguments: ['%param.languages[en]%']
```

Or something like that... I've no idea how to do this ^^'

Can you help me :) ?

Comment: Try ['%param.languages.en%']. You will get an array with the items 0 => en and 1 => fr.

Comment: I've tested this, and I've an error, Symfony said "param.languages.en must be defined" :(

Answer (score 1):

If you use `%...%` format you can get parameters only by the highest name - `param.languages`.

If you want to get determine parameter e.g. `param.languages.en` you must use expression language:

```
services:
    app.mailer:
        class:     AppBundle\Mailer
        arguments: ["@=container.getParameter('param.languages')['en']"]
```

More info here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html